# Buildserver for MonoTouch upon OS X?

Tags: continuous-integration, xamarin.ios

I am taking my first steps in the world of iPhone/iPad development with MonoTouch and wish to adopt the practices that I adhere to in my "day" job.

Is there a buildserver for OS X that plays nice with MonoTouch/Nunit?

Thanks kindly,

Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have MonoDevelop and MonoTouch installed, you can build solutions using the MonoDevelop commandline tool:

```
/Applications/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/mdtool build
```

For options, run

```
/Applications/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/mdtool build --help
```

Comment: I don't think this is a great answer. This is a question I've been struggling with for a while. I have some scripting that is done to automate the build (huge hassle), but I can't seem to build a server that will make automated builds, or let any of the devs make a build outside of their dev environment. The command line tools are handy to automation, but don't help very much with a real build server.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you'd get the actual iPhone project to build but of you farm out as much as you can to seperate projects so only the bits that need the funky MT references are in the central UI project you can at least build the rest as normal.

I've just started using TinyIoc which will help in this regard.

As for a specific build server - isnt TeamCity built using Java and Appache? If so there should be no reason why this won't work on your OSX.

That said - why would you want the build server on the same physical machine you dev on?